# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException while trying to save the core data

Tags: core-data, swift

I have a problem when trying to save my record to core data. The idea is to save a simple student information into the core data database. You can see the detail below.

My Entity class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Student: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var id: String
@NSManaged var firstname: String
@NSManaged var lastname: String
@NSManaged var age: NSNumber
@NSManaged var email: String

}
```

The code is :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddControllerViewController: UIViewController {
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

@IBOutlet var id: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var firstname: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var lastname: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var age: UITextField!


@IBOutlet var email: UITextField!


@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entityDescripition = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Student", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let student =  Student(entity: entityDescripition!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    student.id = id.text
    student.firstname = firstname.text
    student.lastname = lastname.text
    student.age = age.text.toInt()!
    student.email = email.text
    managedObjectContext?.save(nil)

    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

and the error message i was getting :

```
 2014-10-14 16:31:42.098 Registration[3829:119352] -[Registration.Student setId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc667a77070

 2014-10-14 16:31:42.105 Registration[3829:119352] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Registration.Student setId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc667a77070'
```

Has anybody had similar error before and found the way to fix it ?

When i put the break point i got these :

```
2014-10-14 21:52:49.227 Registration[513:9236] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Registration.Student setId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe441c3d100'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001062593f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107d87bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010626050d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061b87fc ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001061b8398 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Registration                        0x0000000105cbc887 _TFC12Registration27AddControllerViewController4savefS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 935
6   Registration                        0x0000000105cbcd02 _TToFC12Registration27AddControllerViewController4savefS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 66
7   UIKit                               0x0000000106ae49ee -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
8   UIKit                               0x0000000106ae49ee -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
9   UIKit                               0x0000000106beabd0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
10  UIKit                               0x0000000106be9f9f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 522
11  UIKit                               0x0000000106b2a3b8 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 735
12  UIKit                               0x0000000106b2ace3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 683
13  UIKit                               0x0000000106af7ae1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
14  UIKit                               0x0000000106b04bad _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 17370
15  UIKit                               0x0000000106ae0233 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1961
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010618ead1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010618499d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106183fd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106183a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a3489f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
21  UIKit                               0x0000000106ae3550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
22  Registration                        0x0000000105cc070e top_level_code + 78
23  Registration                        0x0000000105cc074a main + 42
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108561145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint to catch All Exceptions and see where exactly its crashing. Is it at this line `student.id = id.text`?

Comment: i replaced all text input with constant value, the same error still occurs. student.id = "2000" etc.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint?

Comment: If you comment out the assignment to `id` does it crash on the `firstname` line?  (I'm wondering whether it's not liking "id" as a name or not dealing well with `Student`.)

Comment: But as you can see on my Student NSManagedObject, there is id declared as string. I just wonder where the "setId" is coming from if you see on the error message. "-[Registration.Student setId:]: unrecognised selector....."